# RAID10 with 24 drives on Linux

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have an Ubuntu server with attached 24x1TB drives, which I would like to use for storage.

I would like to use RAID10 with ext4, but all examples I saw (such as http://www.emind.co/how-to/create-software-raid-10-with-mdadm), are using 4 drives - not 24.

Are there any specific options I need to consider when using so many drives together?

How do I set it up for 24 drives using mdadm?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these drives built in to the server or are they external to the server? If they are internal, are they being controlled by a RAID controller? If this is the case, then you don't need to use mdadm. The RAID controller will handle the RAID and simply pass the volumes to your OS.- Sorry, this completely dodges your question, just making sure you're on the right track to begin with.

Comment: This is a server at a hosting provider, I wasn't able to figure out whether drives have a hardware RAID, so I preferred a safe bet such as mdadm :)

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing your workload before going down this path.  I have a server with 24 4TB Data drives in two 12 disk raid6, and 2 boot drives in a raid1.  The workload is such that IO gets saturated and the machine runs like a dog, even though there's heaps of CPU and memory.  Perhaps raid6 was a poor choice, but the disks aren't new.   If you're using this thing just for storing data then it'll be fine, but barman database backups were too big to swallow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "caveat" would be that this command:

> mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level raid10 --name data --raid-disks 4 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1

Would actually be

> mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level raid10 --name data --raid-disks 24 /dev/sd{a,b,c,d,e,f, and so on}1

Or better

> mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level raid10 --name data --raid-disks 24 /dev/sd{a-z}1 
>   Not sure of last one... Give it a try with file creation first...
>   Not much changes here...

Comment: It might be better to use `--raid-disks 22` or `--raid-disks 23` in order to use one or two disks as hot spares.

Comment: Indeed. This only is a example. As well, I don't know much about your hardware setup or budget$. But you might want to check for a hardware RAID controller... Theses have batteries and might save your life if you have power loss...

Answer (score 0):

`mdadm` and the other pieces of the Linux Software Raid are perfectly capable to manage 24 drives. Simply follow one of the many Linux RAID10 tutorials.